# ApachePOI Null Pointer Exception

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am running into a strange null pointer exception when attempting to create a sheet using ApachePOI. I require a more modular code as this is part of a larger system. I have been unable to find any similar examples online, all examples are stored within a main method.
I am also wondering when it is necessary to include a `workbook.write(outputStream)` does this need to be in every method that a new sheet/workbook/row/cell is created or only when I am writing data to the sheets (like in the write method)?

```
public class ExcelWriter {

    private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private String outputFile;
    private ArrayList<XSSFSheet> sheets;
    private static int sheetCount;

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Constructor --> initializes a workbook
    public ExcelWriter(String outputFile) throws IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        this.outputFile=outputFile;
        sheets=new ArrayList<XSSFSheet>();
        sheetCount=0;

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        workbook.write(os);
        os.close();
    }

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Method to create a new sheet in the workbook, add to sheet list
    public void newSheet(String sheetName) throws IOException {
        sheets.add(workbook.createSheet(sheetName)); //ERROR HERE****
        sheetCount++;

         FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
         workbook.write(os);
         os.close();
    }

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Method to write a cell into a worksheet given sheet row and column
    public void write(int sheet,int row, int col, String data) {

        XSSFSheet tempSheet=sheets.get(sheet);
        System.out.println("yest");

        // Specific row number 
        XSSFRow tempRow = tempSheet.createRow(row); 

        // Specific cell number 
        XSSFCell cell = tempRow.createCell(col); 

        // putting value at specific position 
        cell.setCellValue(data); 

        // writing the content to Workbook 
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            workbook.write(os);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: `Wordbook.write` always writes the whole workbook. If done, the workbook object cannot be changed further without creating (reading) it new. So `Wordbook.write` should only be done **once** after all changes where made. In your case the `XSSFWorkbook workbook` cannot be changed further after `... new ExcelWriter(outputFile); ` since the `ExcelWriter` constructor already had written it out.

Comment: @AxelRichter This makes sense, Is there a way to continuously add to a workbook Or would I have to save all the data and do it all in one `.write()`? I am trying to make this class a tool that can be used to write excel cells using the write method.

Comment: I would do only **one** `Workbook.write` after all changes to the workbook. Else after each `Workbook.write` the workbook needs to be read new from the file. This can be done using `WorkbookFactory.create` for example.